# Separating Interface and Implementation in C++

Tags: c++

If I have a simple header file:

```
namespace aNamespace {
    class AClass {
        public:
        AClass();
        ~AClass();

        bool Init();
        void Shutdown();
    };
}
```

What is the 'correct' way to implement this class in the corresponding CPP file? I can see two options:

**Option A**

```
namespace aNamespace {
    class AClass {
        public:
        AClass() { ... }
        ~AClass() { ... }

        bool Init() { ... }
        void Shutdown() { ... }
    };
}
```

**Option B**

```
namespace aNamespace {
    AClass::AClass() { ... }
    AClass::~AClass() { ... }

    bool AClass::Init() { ... }
    void AClass::Shutdown() { ... }
}
```

---

The problem I see with **Option B** is that it's hard to add implementation-specific members to `AClass` - e.g. what if the implementation requires a `std::wstring` or so as a storage variable; but that variable isn't defined in the header file?

The reason I'm asking this is because I may wish to have multiple implementations of `AClass`, and select which one to link according to some external variable (e.g. the target platform or architecture).

Comment: A won't work, that'd redefine the already defined `AClass`. To hide implementation specific members (variables and private methods), the pattern usually applied is the "pimpl idiom".

Comment: I don't think Option A is even legal... assuming you include the header in the CPP, this is a "redefinition" of a class.

Comment: Option B with #ifdef's for implementation specific stuff ?

Comment: @ThePluc The point is that I don't want storage variables declared at namespace scope

Comment: It sounds like you should look at the *pimpl idiom* as recommended by others. See [this gotw](http://herbsutter.com/gotw/_100/) for example. And it is not clear how option A could work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another option would be to actually make name of each implementation platform specific and have a simple typedef switch in header to control which one is chosen based on target/architecture:

```
#ifdef target1
typedef AClass Target1ClassImplementation;
#elif  defined target2
typedef AClass Target2ClassImplementation;
#else
#error AClass is not implemented for current target
#endif
```

If desired, common interface can be encapsulated in a base class implementations derive from. It is less error prone since is more explicit in sense which implementation is for what target, while allows using AClass regardlesss of a platform target outside of header.

Answer (score 0):

B is much better in most cases:

Advantages:

- Hide implementation details.
- Less #includes in header files (less exposed dependencies!):

  - Faster builds
  - 2 classes can call each other's functions. Very tricky to do if both are in headers.
  - Changes to implementation do affect other classes (build time).

Disadvantages:
  - Functions in CPP file do not inline in other modules (across library boundaries)

Optimal: Decide per function which is best. Short one liners to the header and longer ones to the cpp(s). You can have more than 1 source file for the class implementation.